# zookeeper connection is hanged out while transferring data from hbase thrift server..?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

```
016-01-05 00:39:11,283 DEBUG [thrift-worker-5] thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: scannerGetList: id=116
2016-01-05 00:39:31,798 DEBUG [thrift-worker-4] thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: scannerGetList: id=117
2016-01-05 00:39:32,449 DEBUG [thrift-worker-4] thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: scannerGetList: id=117
2016-01-05 00:40:10,968 INFO  [ConnectionCleaner] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x352103c1cb50008
2016-01-05 00:40:10,975 INFO  [ConnectionCleaner] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x352103c1cb50008 closed
2016-01-05 00:40:11,003 INFO  [thrift-worker-0-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

The zookeeper connection is hanged out during accessing the records from hbase thrift server to client connection.  After restarting the connection they continue to access the records.  What are the possible reasons for zookeeper connection hanged out during access data from hbase thrift server?

Comment: what is the question?? Please see ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center and provide more information!!

Comment: The question is zookeeper connection  is hanged out during accessing the records from hbase thrift server to client connection.after restarting the connection they  continue to access the records.Please suggest possible reasons for zookeeper conection hanged out during access data from hbase thrift server..?

Comment: what do you mean by hanged out?  it looks like an idle ZK session is being closed.   is there a particular issue that you end up seeing aside from these log messages?

Comment: hi..thanks for the reply,actually issue is  cache problem in thrift server.this is already be a issue in hbase version..now that issue is fixed in another version.For more details please refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14196